# Cannot use StreamReader method

Tags: c#, string, streamreader

I'm trying to read a text file with **StreamReader** method but it doesn't work. I research all topics and forums but the solutions doesn't work on my project. My text file is in c/users/user/documents/VS15/Projects/MyProject/*here*

```
string filename = "text.txt";
    TextReader fi = new StreamReader(filename);
```

I get this error:

> " A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'MainPage.filename' "

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try too put it in method for example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string filename = "text.txt";
    TextReader fi = new StreamReader(filename);
}
```

or make your variable static :

```
public static string filename = "text.txt";
```

Comment: Now it's says " Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context. " and "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream' "

Comment: public static string filename = "razpisanie.txt"; TextReader fi = new StreamReader(filename); short n = fi.ReadLine() ; / / then I will use that and other variables from this text file to my program.I don't have to have a method for this. It's says "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream' "

Comment: True because fi.ReadLine() return string, but you try to convert it to short, try this "string n=fi.ReadLine()"

Comment: I've done it. It's says I can't convert from string to System.IO.Stream again.

Comment: It's said on that string or another? TextReader fi = new StreamReader(filename);

Comment: Look here,  example below. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, "TextReader fi = new StreamReader(filename);" - that's where the error comes from. Also, in the example, there's "using" but I want to read many times. If I use 'using' every time when I declare a new variable to read it, It'll read the first line every time.

Comment: @Dimsn Check your file, have you got at top using System.IO; ?

Comment: In my text file, no, I don't have

Answer (score 0):

It's a compile time error. Move your code to the body of method. Change from:

```
class C {

    string filename = "text.txt";
    TextReader fi = new StreamReader(filename);

    private void myMethod() {
        // ....
    }

}
```

to:

```
class C {

    string filename = "text.txt";

    private void myMethod() {
         TextReader fi = new StreamReader(filename);
         // ....
    }

}
```

or place the code in the constructor:

```
class C {

    string filename = "text.txt";
    TextReader fi;

    public C() {
         fi = new StreamReader(filename);
    }

    private void myMethod() {
         // you can use the fi variable here
    }

}
```

Comment: but what if I don't want to use method ?

Comment: @Dimsn What do you mean by "don't want to use method"? So where are you trying to put your code? Could you please provide some example of your code?

Comment: public static string filename = "razpisanie.txt";
        TextReader fi = new StreamReader(filename); short n = fi.ReadLine() ; / / then I will use that and other variables from this text file to my program.I don't have to have a method for this. It's says "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream' "

Comment: public sealed partial class MainPage : Page - that's the class where is my code

Comment: @Dimsn You can't use fi.ReadLine() outside of method's body. You can't change it.